# Cannot connect to specific port

Tags: silverlight, soap, wcf-ria-services

I've encountered the following issue:
Let's say I have a WCF RIA service that's exposed via SOAP endpoint so other non-sl clients are able to consume its functionality.
The things work out shiny when I try to connect locally e.g. http://localhost:[portnumber]/Services/[ServiceName].svc
As soon as I replace the localhost with the actual machine name I'm unable to consume the services even locally (actually only one of them is reachable whilst the others magically disappear).
Trying to connect from another machine results in an error.
Any hints?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there perhaps a firewall blocking traffic? You say trying to connect from another machine results in an error - what exactly is the error?

Comment: The firewall's off.
No connection could be made because the target machine acively refused it and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Try add [clientaccesspolicy.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (if not added).
[Network Security Access Restrictions in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is good article about security in silverlight. It can be helpful for you.